# Django ORM date field wrong output

Tags: python, django, orm

I want to select the objects that date field equal to the latest date in the model.
So I pick the latest date by

```py
>>> latest_date = StockPrice.objects.latest('date').date
>>> latest_date
datetime.date(2021, 4, 9)
```

but the latest date in my model is **2021-4-13**.
then I tried this

```py
>>> StockPrice.objects.filter(date=latest_date)
<QuerySet []>
```

I use **latest_date** just got,

but nothing show after filtering

Can't figure it out how does this happened.

**./models.py**

```py
class StockPrice(models.Model):

    date = models.DateField()
    symbol = models.IntegerField()
    open = models.FloatField()
    high = models.FloatField()
    low = models.FloatField()
    close = models.FloatField()
    shares = models.IntegerField()
    volume = models.IntegerField()
    pe = models.FloatField()
    pb = models.FloatField()
    yield_rate = models.FloatField()
***

[click to data inserted to the model][1] 

  [1]: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ycy-tw/python-django-stock/main/demodata/stockprice.csv
```

Comment: can you select if you use a string instead of a date object? ie `'2021-04-13'` ?

Comment: still got empty queryset after tried '2021-04-13', '2021-4-13', '2021-4-9', '2021-04-09'.

Comment: that does indeed ssound strange :( sorry i got nothing :/

Comment: that's ok, I just figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Just figure it out!

The confused result was caused by data type.

I use `pd.read_csv` to read the .csv file given in the question and sorted.
After

```py
df.sort_values('date')
```

the latest date still `2021-4-9`.

Then I use

```
df.date = pd.to_datetime('date')
df.to_csv('override where it from')
```

And then,

1. Remove migrations folder under the app
2. Remove db.sqlite3.
3. Reinsert data into db.

Finally, the confused result is no loner available.